# Beginner question about different data types in constructors

Tags: java, types, getter, setter

I'm new to coding and I'm currently working with OOP in Java. My instructor had us create a rectangle class instead of just importing the built-in. Anyway, we were to create constructors featuring ints and doubles as parameters. My questions is, with having two constructors if different data types, do I need separate getters / setters for each type? Would this be a time I could use generic datatypes? I have included what I created below. Thanks.

```
public class Rectangle {
    
    private int height;
    private int width;
    private double doubleHeight;
    private double doubleWidth;
    
    public Rectangle() {
        height = 0;
        width = 0;
    }
    
    public Rectangle(int h, int w) {
        height = h;
        width = w;
        System.out.println("A Rectangle has been created using integer dimensions.");
    }
    
    public Rectangle(double h, double w) {
        doubleHeight = h;
        doubleWidth= w;
        System.out.println("A Rectangle has been created using double dimensions.");
    }
    
    public int getIntHeight() {
        return height;
    }
    
    public double getDoubleHeight() {
        return doubleHeight;
    }
    
    public int setIntHeight(int h) {
        height = h;
    }
    
    public double setDoubleHeight(double h) {
        doubleHeight = h;
    }
    
    public int getIntArea() {
        return width * height;
    }
    
    public double getDoubleArea() {
        return doubleWidth * doubleHeight;
    }
    
    public int getIntPerimeter() {
        return width*2 + height*2;
    }
    
    public double getDoublePerimeter() {
        return doubleWidth*2 + doubleHeight*2;
    }
    
    public String toString() {
        if (this.getIntHeight() >= 1) {
            return "Height: " + height + ", Width: " + width;
        }
        else {
            return "Height: " + doubleHeight + ", Width: " + doubleWidth;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I would think the properties, width and height, within the class should be a double.  The constructor can take integer values and convert those to doubles.  If you require `getIntHeight` etc. you could round the doubles appropriately.

Comment: I agree with @FelixCastor. A rectangle has but one height, so the class probably shouldn't have two different height variables.  (I say 'probably' since one can make up cases where that might be best, but this doesn't look like such a case).

Comment: Not much [tag:oop] about it.

Comment: @user207421 You're right.  Sometimes instructors provide useful and beautiful examples that subtly reinforce principles of object oriented design.  And sometimes they just want to check the box that you know how to overload a constructor.

Comment: It would make sense to have an `IntRectangle` and a `DoubleRectangle` (duplicating code), maybe even `Rectangle<Integer>` and `Rectangle<Double>`. If you just treated _type parameters_ the latter is probably wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need a different getters if you want both types to be accessible. Your setters can have the same names since the parameter types are different. You can make those getters/setters cast, if necessary, to the type used in the constructor. For example:

```
public class Rectangle {

    private int height;
    private int width;
    private double doubleHeight;
    private double doubleWidth;

    public Rectangle() {
        this.height = 0;
        this.width = 0;
    }

    public Rectangle(int h, int w) {
        this.height = h;
        this.width = w;
        System.out.println("A Rectangle has been created using integer dimensions.");
    }

    public Rectangle(double h, double w) {
        this.doubleHeight = h;
        this.doubleWidth = w;
        System.out.println("A Rectangle has been created using double dimensions.");
    }

    public int getIntHeight() {
        if (this.height > 0)
            return this.height;
        else
            return (int) getDoubleHeight();
    }

    public double getDoubleHeight() {
        if (this.doubleHeight > 0)
            return this.doubleHeight;
        else
            return (double) getIntHeight();
    }

    public void setHeight(int h) {
        if (this.height > 0)
            this.height = h;
        else
            setHeight((double) h);
    }

    public void setHeight(double h) {
        if (this.doubleHeight > 0)
            this.doubleHeight = h;
        else
            setHeight((int) h);
    }

    public int getIntArea() {
        if (this.height > 0)
            return this.width * this.height;
        else
            return (int) getDoubleArea();
    }

    public double getDoubleArea() {
        if (this.doubleWidth > 0)
            return this.doubleWidth * this.doubleHeight;
        else
            return (double) getIntArea();
    }

    public int getIntPerimeter() {
        if (this.height > 0)
            return this.width * 2 + this.height * 2;
        else
            return (int) getDoublePerimeter();
    }

    public double getDoublePerimeter() {
        if (this.doubleHeight > 0)
            return this.doubleWidth * 2 + this.doubleHeight * 2;
        else
            return (double) getIntPerimeter();
    }

    public String toString() {
        if (this.height >= 1) {
            return "Height: " + this.height + ", Width: " + this.width;
        } else {
            return "Height: " + this.doubleHeight + ", Width: " + this.doubleWidth;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should store `height` and `width` as doubles (because `double` is wider than `int` – `int` can fit into `double` but `double` can't fit into `int`) and then have constructors with `double` and `int` arguments that simply set the value of double height and width.

There is no need to use generic datatypes.

Here is how it should look like:

```
public class Rectangle {

    private double height;
    private double width;

    public Rectangle() {
        height = 0;
        width = 0;
    }

    public Rectangle(int h, int w) {
        height = h;
        width = w;
        System.out.println("A Rectangle has been created using integer dimensions.");
    }

    public Rectangle(double h, double w) {
        height = h;
        width = w;
        System.out.println("A Rectangle has been created using double dimensions.");
    }

    public double getHeight() {
        return this.height;
    }

    public void setHeight(double h) {
        this.height = h;
    }

    public double getWidth() {
        return this.width;
    }

    public void setWidth(double w) {
        this.width = w;
    }

    public double getArea() {
        return width * height;
    }

    public double getPerimeter() {
        return width * 2 + height * 2;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "Height: " + height + ", Width: " + width;
    }
}
```